# SPF Out of Range

Tags: gmail

I've got my domain set up to use Gmail, and I consistently get a specific error email I email a specific person.

`550 SPF: 209.85.***.*** is not allowed to send mail from example.com`

When I test my record using this tool: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/

I get SPF ranges, that do not include to IP address above, but do include many others.

And... I am lost. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that the Gmail tool is telling you to configure one set of IPs on your domain's SPF record but then uses a different set of IPs to actually send the emails from?

Comment: Gmail just has me set MX records and TXT records fro SPF and DKIM. It doesn't have me set particular IPs.